# Blazor WASM - AzureAD - Login MAX_AGE parameter in URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, blazor, openid-connect, webassembly

Context: I have a Blazor WASM (.Net 6) application, that uses AzureAD to authenticate and get its data from a standalone API (this API does not host the Blasor app). Everything goes well, users authenticate with their Azure AD credential on the Blazor client and get tokens from Microsoft to query the API.

Question: I would like to force a user to reauthenticate after a while regarding certain conditions (for example a user is in a group that has a access to sensitive data). To achieve this I would like to trigger again the authentication process. My goal was to simply make this kind of call :

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/authentication/login?returnUrl=https://localhost:5001/home");
```

The problem is that I haven't found any solution to tell to the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` to set up Max_age parameters when calling Microsoft API. Without this Max_Age parameter, Microsoft api see that the use is already logged in and therefore does nothing, it just redirects to the home page.

Any Idea?

Comment: It's not an option to `NavigateTo` the `/signout-callback-oidc` url?

Comment: I tried but this give me that error : 
```crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Invalid action 'signout-callback-oidc'. ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Honza's blarg'sblog](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/06/forcing-reauthentication-with-azure-ad/) ,  if you can make use of max-age parameter with prompt=login. but is not recommended in most cases.

Also please check the conditional accesspolicy and see if you can set the sign in frequency for the particular app or all apps , all users or particular user/group like below.

> ***Sign-in frequency defines the time period before a user is asked to sign in again when attempting to access a resource.***

In azure ad, in security blade> select conditional access and new policy:

- ***Give it some name, and then select users that has to be re-authenctiacted.***

[image]

- ***Then select the app or all apps according to the requirement ,for which the setting is required.***

[image]

- ***Then the session controls can be granted by setting frequency to 1 hr or required hrs.***

[image]

- ***Enable the policy and create the conditional access.***

**References:**

1. [Forcing re-authentication on (some) applications (azureinfra.com)](https://blog.azureinfra.com/2019/05/27/forcing-re-authentication-on-some-applications/)
2. [Configure authentication session management - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime)